# Найти идентификатор записи в в строке с минимальным числом повторов в mysql

Tags: mysql

Как найти в таблице идентификатор объекта с минимальным числом повторений  в MYSQL.
Вот пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Условию удовлетворяет employee_id = 3, остальные нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT count( employee_id) cnt,   employee_id
   FROM Mytable
        GROUP BY employee_id 
        ORDER BY  cnt ASC 
        LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вы помогли мне